# How to give sharp edges to a shape in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I had no problems creating a grid like in the figure, but I can't create sharp edges at the end of the grid:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: How did you get the "wonky" edges to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the borders of your shape, the problem seems to be your brush. You are using a brush that is not "regular" like the lines inside the grid.

Just select your shape, and go to Brushes (if you can't seem, `Window > Brushes`). Change your stroke to a brush that has the same weight everywhere. The first one in the list should be the 1px solid default.